# Core Plot scrolling interruption

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm using **CPTScatterPlot** to display data, also I have data labels above all plot symbols. I need to detect user touches and using - `plot:dataLabelWasSelectedAtRecordIndex`: to detect it. But if I click on the data label and try to scroll, scrolling is not working.

Is there any way to detect if user touches and yet not interrupt scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem in my code, using graph plot space delegate instead of CPTPlot delegate.

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    _lastPlotSpaceDownPoint=point;
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CGFloat distance = hypotf((_lastPlotSpaceDownPoint.x - point.x), (_lastPlotSpaceDownPoint.y - point.y));
    if (abs(distance) < 5) {
        NSUInteger recordIndex=[self.linePlot indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint:point];
        // your code here
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've made some changes to the event handling and related delegate methods on the `release-2.0` branch of the Core Plot code. Get the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) and switch to the `release-2.0` branch to get the updated code. Note that this update requires the Accelerate framework and raises the minimum system requirements from the 1.x releases on the `master` branch.